# Validating multiple messages on the same JMS endpoint in Citrus Framework

Tags: java, automated-tests, integration-testing, citrus-framework

I'm sending a single message that produces multiple messages, two of which arrive on the same JMS endpoint.

```
runner.send(sendMessageBuilder -> sendMessageBuilder.endpoint(inputMessage.getEndpoint())
    .messageType(MessageType.XML)
    .payload(inputMessage.getPayload())
    .header(JMSOUTPUTCORRELATIONID, correlationId));

for(OutputMessage outputMessage : inputMessage.getOutputMessages()) {
     runner.receive(receiveMessageBuilder -> receiveMessageBuilder.endpoint(outputMessage.getEndpoint())
        .schemaValidation(false)
        .payload(outputMessage.getPayload())
        .header(JMSOUTPUTCORRELATIONID, correlationId));
}
```

When validating two messages on the same endpoint I'm having trouble finding a way to match them to their respective expected outputs.
I was wondering if Citrus has a built in way to do this or if I could build in a condition that checks the other expected outputs if the first one fails.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a custom validator.

```
List<OutputMessage> outputMessages = inputMessage.getOutputMessages();
while(outputMessages.size() > 0) {
    OutputMessage outputMessage = outputMessages.get(0);
    runner.receive(receiveMessageBuilder -> receiveMessageBuilder.endpoint(outputMessage.getEndpoint())
        .schemaValidation(true)
        .validator(new MultipleOutputMessageValidator(outputMessages))
        .header(JMSOUTPUTCORRELATIONID, correlationId));
}
```

The validator is provided with the the list of expected outputs that have not yet been validated. It will then try to validate each of the expected outputs in the list against the received message and if the validation is succesful removes that expected output from the list.

```
public class MultipleOutputMessageValidator extends DomXmlMessageValidator {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultipleOutputMessageValidator.class);
    private List<OutputMessage> controlMessages;

    public MultipleOutputMessageValidator(List<OutputMessage> controlMessages) {
        this.controlMessages = controlMessages;
    }

    @Override
    public void validateMessagePayload(Message receivedMessage, Message controlMessage, XmlMessageValidationContext validationContext, TestContext context) throws ValidationException {
        Boolean isValidated = false;
        for (OutputMessage message : this.controlMessages) {
            try {
                super.validateMessagePayload(receivedMessage, message, validationContext, context);
                isValidated = true;
                controlMessages.remove(message);
                break;
            } catch (ValidationException e) {
                // Do nothing for now
            }
        }
        if (!isValidated) {
            throw new ValidationException("None of the messages validated");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use JMS message selectors so you can "pick" one of the messages from that queue based on a technical identifier. This selector can be a JMS message header for instance (in your case the header `JMSOUTPUTCORRELATIONID`). This way you make sure to receive the message that you want to validate first.

Example usage:

```
receive(action -> action.endpoint(someEndpoint)
            .selector("correlationId='Cx1x123456789' AND operation='getOrders'"));
```

Citrus message selector support is described [here](http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/actions-receive.html#message-selectors)